# $str == *"somestring"* vs the use of regex

Tags: bash

I currenlty have the below bash script working. However, I am unsure if this approach is completely a good one. I am trying to look for substring `test` in the below directory paths. What would be the best appraoch? regex? Looking for some guidance using the below example

```
for str in "/directory/manifest" "directory/test/configs" "directory/test/secrets" "directory/main" "directory/bin"; do
    if [[ $str == *"test"* ]];then
        echo $str
    fi
done
```

Comment: Why do you want to catch `test` in these strings? Are you putting together a list of directories, but you want to exclude directory trees under `test`? There might be a more robust solution with `find`.

Comment: The match operator `=~` is a better option. It is easier to read in my opinion: `[[ $str =~ test ]]`

Comment: Another option would be `shopt -s globstar` and then `for str in **/*test*; do something with $str; done`, if you are looking for every file and directory that match `*test*`.

Comment: Apart from the comparison method, you may need to take care the pathname does not contain  something like `latest`.

Comment: @MaryCoding : If the glob expression does what you want, why are you looking for a regex alternative? Using a regexp is slightly easier to read, as accdias pointed out, but in the end, it depends on which style you like best. BTW, there is no reason to use quotes around the string _test_ in your example. `[[ $str == *test* ]]` would do as well.